# autocomplete with extjs4: can not access to service

Tags: extjs4

I work with extjs 4,

I want to do autocomplete with combobox

meaning when I entered a text in the combobox a request will send to database in order to display a list of emplyees ( in my case ) according to text entered in the combobox

in emplyeesModel.js I have

```
Ext.define('GenericComboModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model', 
        fields: [
             {name: 'label', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'value',  type: 'string'}
        ]
 });

 var employeesStore= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'GenericComboModel',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: 'employeesService',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'users'
         }
     }
 });
```

in emplyeesView.js I have

```
{
  xtype: 'combobox',
  store: employeesStore,
  displayField: 'label',
  valueField: 'value',
  queryMode: 'remote',
  fieldLabel: 'test',
  editable: false,
  id: 'employees_IdCombo',
  hideTrigger:true
  queryParam: 'searchStr' 

}
```

in the service employeesService.java I have

```
public class employeesService{

 public List<employees> getEmployeesListByLibelle(String libelle) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Query query = getSession().createQuery("FROM employees emp where emp.libelle=:libelle ");  
query.setParameter("libelle", libelle);
            List result = query.list();
            if(result.size()!=0 && result !=null)
                return result;
            else 
                return null;
        }

}
```

but when I run my example I have this errror :

```
GET http://localhost:8080/employeesService.getEmployeesListByLibelle?_dc=1376728740208&searchStr=testSearch&page=1&start=0&limit=25&filter=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22label%22%7D%5D 404 (Introuvable) ext-all-rtl.js:21
```

Comment: I think that the service class should have the syntax of servlet, but I didn't know if this is a solution or  no

Comment: How can `url: 'employeesService'` become `employeesService.getEmployeesListByLibelle`? And does http://localhost:8080/employeesService also return a 404?